# Is there any char to hexadecimal function for C?

Tags: c, hex

I have a char array with data from a text file and I need to convert it to hexadecimal format.
Is there such a function for C language.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you be more explicit?  What base are the number in the file currently in, 10 or 16?  What do you want to do with those number -- convert them to integers that you can use or translate them from one base to another?  "Hexadecimal" really has no meaning as an internal format -- that's just one of several formats you could use to visualize the internal binary representation.

Comment: @geOrge007: You're getting various answers to the questions because of its ambiguity.  I second tvanfosson's comment, and suggest you supply an example or two of how the data is and how you 'd like converted.

Comment: Sorry guys i am a little confused myself thats why i am not really clear.
Here is the problem...
I am really newbie at cryptography and now i have to make a password manager as an exercise. So the char array i am telling is basically the contents of the text file that contains usernames and passwords. I will use aes algorithm to encrypt the file and someone told me that i have to make the contents of the char array at hexademical format. As i didn't do something like that before i thought that it will be something like that:http://www.string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx

Comment: Here is the aes implementation that i am using if someone ask:http://www.gzsec.com/filesys/news_view.asp?newsid=234

Thanks again:D

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly (no guarantees there), you have a text string representing a number in decimal format ("1234"), and you want to convert it to a string in hexadecimal format ("4d2").

Assuming that's correct, your best bet will be to convert the input string to an integer using either `sscanf()` or `strtol()`, then use `sprintf()` with the `%x` conversion specifier to write the hex version to another string:

```
char text[] = "1234";
char result[SIZE]; // where SIZE is big enough to hold any converted value
int val;

val = (int) strtol(text, NULL, 0); // error checking omitted for brevity
sprintf(result, "%x", val);
```

Comment: +1 for good alternate interpretation of the question, and reasonable answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you want to be able to display the hex values of individual byes in your array, sort of like the output of a dump command.   This is a method of displaying one byte from that array.

The leading zero on the format is needed to guarantee consistent width on output.
You can upper or lower case the X, to get upper or lower case representations.
I recommend treating them as unsigned, so there is no confusion about sign bits.

```
unsigned char c = 0x41;
printf("%02X", c);
```

Comment: The question specifies _I have a char array with data from a text file_. A char array in C is typically a C string of text, from the text file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `atoi` and `sprintf` / `snprintf`. Here's a simple example.

```
char* c = "23";
int number = atoi(c);
snprintf( buf, sizeof(buf), "%x", number );
```

Comment: What is the 'atoi()' doing?  If c is '`char c;`' (as is conventional, when it isn't '`int c;`', which is appropriate for I/O from `getc()` etc), the code won't compile.

Comment: From the original question, _"I have a char array"_, so `c` is a `char*` pointer to a character. I'll make that clearer. Thanks.